# scala filtering list of strings with multiple commas

Tags: string, scala, list, split

I am very new to Scala and I am not even sure how to describe my question properly, but I will do my best to explain with examples.
I want to filter a list of strings with a condition but that list contains a lot of commas. The list contains `userID`, `artID` and ratings. eg)

```
val lst = List("1,1,4", "1,1060,2", "3,123,5", "4,1210,5", "4,1213,4")
```

With `3,123,5` as an example, `3` is the `userID`, `123` is the `artID` and `5` is the rating.
What I want to do is take the ratings that is above 4 and return a list of (`userID`, `artID`) only (return as `List[(String, String)]`). I've been trying various ways but kept failing and I have no idea how to begin now.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to filter a "list of strings." So I take it your input might look like this.

```
val lst = List("1,1,4", "1,1060,2", "3,123,5", "4,1210,5", "4,1213,4")
```

That being the case there is the problem of making numeric comparisons of `String` elements.

```
"4"  < "5"  //true
"14" > "5"  //false
```

You can cast the `String` to an `Int` before comparison, but that should also include tests for casting failure.

Here's a slightly different approach that simply passes all `rating` strings, numeric or otherwise, that evaluates as greater than `"4"`. Strings that don't `split()` into the correct number of sub-strings are filtered out.

```
lst.map(_.split(",")).collect{
  case Array(uID,aID,r) if r.length > 1 || r > "4" => (uID,aID)
}
//res0: List[(String,String)] = List((3, 123), (4, 1210))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val lst = List("1,1,4", "1,1060,2", "3,123,5", "4,1210,5", "4,1213,4")

val res = lst
  .map(_.split(","))
  .collect {
    case Array(a,b,c) if c.toInt>4 => (a,b)
  }

println(res)
```

Comment: I get an error  at case List(a,b,c) if c>4 => (a,b)
                                                         ^
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;

is there any way to return it as List[(String, String)] ??

Comment: do you have `val lst = List(1,1,4, 1,1060,2, 3,123,5, 4,1210,5, 4,1213,4)` or `val lst = List("1,1,4", "1,1060,2", "3,123,5", "4,1210,5", "4,1213,4")` as an input? I mean `lst` var contains only array of values or list of strings like "3,123,5"  ?

Comment: I am sorry I confused you, it's the latter one, val lst = List("1,1,4", "1,1060,2", "3,123,5", "4,1210,5", "4,1213,4")

Comment: added to answer

Comment: It works very well. Thank you very much! I have one more question, is it not possible to use grouped(3) instead of sliding?

Comment: good  catch. it's even more readable. added this to the answer.

Comment: and added one more fix to make the code more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
scala> val lst = List("1,1,4", "1,1060,2", "3,123,5", "4,1210,5", "4,1213,4")
lst: List[String] = List(1,1,4, 1,1060,2, 3,123,5, 4,1210,5, 4,1213,4)

scala> lst.filter(x=> { val y=x.split(",").map(_.toInt); y(2)>4}).map(x=>{val y = x.split(","); (y(0),y(1))} )
res16: List[(String, String)] = List((3,123), (4,1210))

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in various ways:

```
val lst = List("1,1,4", "1,1060,2", "3,123,5", "4,1210,5", "4,1213,4")

  val ans: List[(String, String)] = lst.filter(elem => elem.split(",")(2).toInt > 4).map { e =>
    val s = e.split(",")
    (s(0), s(1))
  }

  val ans2: List[(String, String)] = lst.map {
    _.split(",")
  } collect {
    case Array(a, b, c) if c.toInt > 4 => (a, b)
  }

  val ans3: List[(String, String)] = lst.foldLeft(List[(String, String)]()) {
    (a, b) => {
      val sp = b.split(",")
      if (sp(2).toInt > 4) {
        (sp(0), sp(1)) :: a
      } else a
    }
  }

  println(ans) //List((3,123), (4,1210))
  println(ans2) //List((3,123), (4,1210))
  println(ans3) //List((4,1210), (3,123))
```